# Bash Script How to find every file in folder and run command on it

Tags: bash

So im trying to create a script that looks in a folder and finds all the file types that have .cpp and run g++ on them. so far i have but it doesn't run it says unexpected end

```
for i in `find /home/Phil/Programs/Compile -name *.cpp` ; do echo $i ; 
done
```

Thanks

Comment: What shell are you using, and on which operating system?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that the wildcard `*` is being expanded by the shell before being passed to find. Quote it thusly:

```
for i in `find /home/Phil/Programs/Compile -name '*.cpp'` ; do echo $i ;  done
```

`xargs` as suggested by others is a good solution for this problem, though.

Answer (score 3):

`find` has an option for doing exactly that:

```
find /p/a/t/h -name '*.cpp' -exec g++ {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use xargs like:

`find folder/ -name "*.cpp" | xargs g++`

Or if you want to handle files which contain whitespaces:

`find folder/ -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 g++`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs):

For example:

```
find /home/Phil/Programs/Compile -name *.cpp | xargs g++
```

Comment: did you mean to do find twice

Comment: No, this was a typo by Bryan.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find /home/administrator/Desktop/testfolder -name *.cpp` ; do echo $i ; 
done
```

I get:

```
administrator@Netvista:~$ /home/administrator/Desktop/test.sh
/home/administrator/Desktop/testfolder/main.cpp
/home/administrator/Desktop/testfolder/main2.cpp
```

Comment: ./bashscript.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./bashscript.sh: line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: What are the names of your files?

Comment: @user2872510 Are you on cygwin? Possible Windows `\r\n` line feeds in script?

Comment: Your code worked because you were lucky/unlucky enough not to have any *.cpp files in your home directory, so `*.cpp` was passed unmolested through to find.

Comment: Ooh. I knew that it was some wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

How about using xargs like this:

```
find $working_dir -type f -name *.cpp | xargs -n 1 g++
```